# How to kill process on GPUs with PID in nvidia-smi using keyword?

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, keyword, pid

How to kill running processes on GPUs for a specific program (e.g. python) in terminal?
For example two processes are running with python in the top picture and kill them to see the bottom picture in nvidia-smi

[image: For example two processes are running with python in the top picture and kill them to see the bottom picture in nvidia-smi]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can `grep` "python" in the `nvidia-smi` and then pass the `PID` to
the `kill -9` command, e.g.

```
sudo kill -9 $( nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | sed -n 's/|\s*[0-9]*\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*.*/\1/p' |  sed '/^$/d')
```

Comment: Where do I mention PID??

Comment: @oya163 it should grab it using grep from nvidia-smi. No need to manually add it.

Comment: No I meant a user-specific PID? Because I don't want to and I can't kill other's PID.

Comment: @oya163 in this case you may try: sudo kill -9 PID

Comment: had to change to  awk '{ print $5}' but this worked.

Answer (score 67):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me, probably because `nvidia-smi` has different formats across different versions/hardware.

I'm using a much cleaner command:

```
nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -n1 kill -9
```

You can replace `$3` in the awk expression to fit your `nvidia-smi` output. It is the n-th column in which the PIDs occur.

Comment: Same here, accepted answer didn't work. This one did. Kudos !!

Comment: I needed to sudo kill
`nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $3 }' | sudo xargs -n1 kill -9`

Comment: hmm, this command gives me `kill: argument couldn't be read: '1-nan'`

Comment: `kill -9 <pid>` works. use `sudo` wisely.

Comment: had to change to awk '{ print $5}' but this worked

Comment: for me, `nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $5 }' | xargs -n1 kill -9` worked.

Answer (score 17):

Use `nvidia-smi` or top command to see processes running and to kill command:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: This answer is addressed as a comment in response to 
@oya163 under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

I guess the question is already answered when nvidia-smi shows processes occupying GPU mem. For me, even though nvidia-smi wasnt showing any processes, GPU memory was being used and I wanted to kill them.

The way to go in this case was to use the fuser command to find out the processes using the particular GPU device. In my case I wanted to kill all the processes using the GPU device 3.
This can be done using the command :

```
sudo fuser -k /dev/nvidia3
```

You can use -ki to kill the processes interactively.

Answer (score 7):

As one of other answers suggest you can use: (replace 5 with the column number where process id exists)

```
nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $5 }' | xargs -n1 kill -9
```

If you might have to use this a lot you can create an alias for the command: to do that do this you should edit `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

and add the following line to it and save the file:

```
alias killgpuprocess="nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $5 }' | xargs -n1 kill -9"
```

then (just needed this time):

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then if you run

```
killgpuprocess
```

it will kill the existing processes on GPU(s).

Comment: I had to use 5 instead of 3 for the top-voted answer to work.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping here as a reference. In case one wants to kill all running processes on the gpu, following command would work:

```
nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader | xargs -n1 kill -9
```

Comment: In a see of awks and greps, this is the only thing that worked for me. Thank you.