# CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to install torch with CUDA support.

Here is the result of my `collect_env.py` script:

```
PyTorch version: 1.7.1+cu101
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 10.1
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect

Python version: 3.9 (64-bit runtime)
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 10.1.243
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1080
Nvidia driver version: 460.39
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.19.2
[pip3] torch==1.7.1+cu101
[pip3] torchaudio==0.7.2
[pip3] torchvision==0.8.2+cu101
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl  
[conda] cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0  
[conda] mkl                       2020.2                      256  
[conda] mkl-service               2.3.0            py39he8ac12f_0  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py39h54f3939_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.0.2            py39h63df603_0  
[conda] numpy                     1.19.2           py39h89c1606_0  
[conda] numpy-base                1.19.2           py39h2ae0177_0  
[conda] torch                     1.7.1+cu101              pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchaudio                0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.8.2+cu101              pypi_0    pypi

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the output of `nvcc - V`

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243
```

Finally, here is the output of `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.39       Driver Version: 460.39       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P0    46W / 180W |    624MiB /  8116MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       873      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                101MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1407      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                419MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2029      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       90MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I try to run

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

I get the following error:

```
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

I have performed a reboot, and I have followed the post-installation steps as detailed in [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#mandatory-post)

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve your problem? I am having the same issue on Google VM after a restart...

Comment: had the same issue in google vm after reboot. fix is to create a new conda environment for torch and install cuda 11.4 for debian: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=10&target_type=deb_local

Comment: i had the same issue. after i installed CUDA and torch all went normal. then suddenly this error occurred. it's magically fixed it self after a restart...

Comment: This may not be of any value to the OP, but in my case, this bug happened after putting my Debian session to sleep, waking it up the day later. A simple reboot fixed it, so no need for me to directly jump to painstaking re-installation processes !

Answer (score 80):

Had the same issue and in my case solution was very easy, however it wasn't easy to find it. I had to remove and insert nvidia_uvm module. So:

```
> sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
> sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

That's all. Just before these command collect_env.py reported "Is CUDA available: False". After: "Is CUDA available: True"

Comment: Why exactly does this happen? I end up having to do this fairly often.

Comment: I guess the NVIDIA kernel module is just too damn fragile and breaks randomly. You can consider `sudo modprobe -r nvidia_uvm && sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm` to be workaround that avoids restarting the whole computer to workaround the driver problem.

Comment: Worked for me. I have to run it after un-suspend.

Comment: Usually either /dev/nvidia-uvm /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools are missing, or its major/minor device numbers are wrong (see `ls -l /dev/nvidia-uvm*` - I've seen major device numbers being 511 and 235). When one re-installs or un- and reloads the nvidia_uvm module, the device file gets unlinked/re-created and the problem is fixed.

Comment: I first had to stop any process that use the driver. I used this command `nvidia-smi --query-compute-apps=pid --format=csv,noheader | xargs -n1 kill -9` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005147/4295037

Comment: I did not require to use the -r option in mobprobe to get it working without restarting.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, for me I found a solution at: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/49081

More specifically:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thankyouthankyouthankyouthankyou.

I tried rmmod/modprobing nvidia_uvm (as suggested above) to no avail, but this solved it.  I am using an eGPU with the nVidia card in it, so this might be the reason it is needed.  (It doesn't seem necessary on other machines with internal nVidia GPUs)

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I don't know how to explain it. I just did my own research and found a solution. I wanted to make the process easier for anyone who encounters the problem in the future, so I added it to this question. If you know how to explain it, then you can add your own answer to the question, or add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was running `torch.tensor([3.0,6.0,9.0],dtype=float,device="cuda",requires_grad=False)` in jupyter notebook plugin running in vs code and it worked the first time and didn't work after the computer went to sleep(with the warning above). A simple restart did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```bash
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

I just reboot / restart the system and the problem is solved.