# How to kill training on specific GPUs?

Tags: linux, pytorch, parallel-processing, nvidia, huggingface-transformers

I am training transformers model on differtnt GPUs(3 gpus out of 8) and want to kill training on spesfic gpus only `(0,6,7)`
I trained `top` command I can see only `PID` [image]. But don't know which GPUs belong to `PID`
THE kill -9  I do not want to use because don't know which GPU will stop as I want to stop (0,7,6) and keep the others running

I reproduce the problem with a small example :

```
from accelerate import Accelerator, notebook_launcher
from accelerate.utils import set_seed

def training_loop():
    set_seed(42)
    accelerator = Accelerator(mixed_precision="fp16")
    print("Hello There!")
    # main()   
notebook_launcher(training_loop(),  num_processes=2) #training_loop(),
```

lunching the script with termonal :

`CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,6,7`

`python3 AccelerateTrainer.py`

I expect after running `Nvidia-smi`  `0%` for both 0,6, and 7 GPUs

Comment: Doesn't your `nvidia-smi` gives pids related to GPU ids?

Comment: I believe nvidia-smi don't give pids as I see in the attached image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310416/610569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this `Linux` command that can list all the past or current starting processes:

`ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd -u user_name | grep -i python3`
And then kill specific GPUs by following the command after I know which script running on specific GPUs
`kill -9 <process_id>`

Answer (score 1):

Below the `nvidia-smi` table you should have a list of processes. If you are in a docker container, you need to exit it to see the list of PID. From there you will be able to target which process is taking up memory and kill it.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the processes despite of running same command `nvidia-smi` I am using vscode ssh